# Expression to display Image in MapTips?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, vbscript

In ArcMap, is it possible to display an image by using a path in the attribute table to show an image in MapTips?

Any Python or vbScript expression are welcome as long as it is MapTips which shows the image.

I do not want to use HTML Popus.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to show an image in a map tip, since map tips are designed to show text only. I think you'll need to use an HTML popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to display an image or picture using MapTips.

However, there is an existing ArcGIS Idea titled [Pictures with maptips in desktop](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004PMfIAM) which seems to describe the same functionality that you seek:

> maptips expand to not only show the field values but to also show a
>   picture at the location/spot when hovering over it